# How to generate basic CRUD in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, crud

I'm new in Symfony and I was wondering if there is a way to generate basic CRUD elements for database, preferably with Bootstrap 3. Other frameworks (Laravel, CakePHP) set you off with a functional application.

Answer (score 2):

The best bundle IMHO is [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) by Javier Eguiluz.

But you can also look at [AdminGeneratorBundle](http://symfony2admingenerator.org) and [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin)

All of these bundles use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

By default the command is run in the interactive mode and asks questions to determine the entity name, the route prefix or whether or not to generate write actions:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

To deactivate the interactive mode, use the --no-interaction option but don't forget to pass all needed options:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=AcmeBlogBundle:Post --format=annotation --with-write --no-interaction
```